# How could I know amount of connections to channel in phoenix?

Tags: websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a pretty simple chat application, and I want to implement some specific actions when user exits from the page (that is, `terminate/2` connection). But I want to implement this action if there is nobody else connected to this topic.

How could I do that?

Comment: I haven't really looked into it myself, but I know you can track how many people are connected to a given channel using [Phoenix Presence](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Presence.html)

Comment: Justin, this solution looks nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may sound like a trivial problem but it is not. You need to deal with connectivity issues and so on. Luckily this is a common enough problem that there's a standard solution for it, which comes bundled with Phoenix - `Phoenix.Presence`. It will allow you to reliably track online users for a given topic.

Follow the steps here to set up Presence: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Presence.html

Then in your `terminate/2` callback, you can check if all users left the topic with

```
if Presence.list(socket) |> Enum.empty? do
  # do something
end
```

Comment: It's especially difficult to do if my `do something` is async too :) Thanks!